# Is the COM object CDO for Windows 2000 installed by default?

Tags: windows

I have an application that uses the COM object CDO for Windows 2000 underneath. Is it installed by default on any version of Windows greater than 2000 up until 10?

Is there a way I can check this easily by myself as well?

Comment: Windows could exist without it.  There are dozens upon dozens of core functionality that requires COM support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDOSYS is available on Windows 2000 and onwards by installing the SMTP service, which is part of the Internet Information Server (IIS) Windows feature.